# three js move camera in linear direction right

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need help moving the 3d camera in a linear motion. When I use the code below it rotates the camera around the object , but I need to move the camera along the side of the object.

**I want this:**

[image]

**But I get this:**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```js
function MovePositionRight() {
                  var X, sCurrentX;
                  var sCurrentX = viewer.camera.position.z;
               
                  X =  viewer.camera.position.z - 0.5;
                  
                 MovePositionZ(viewer.camera.position.x, viewer.camera.position.y, X);
              }
 function MovePositionZ(X,Y,Z) {
                  //viewer.camera.position.set(0, 0, 15);
                   
                  viewer.camera.position.set(X, Y, Z);
                  viewer.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                  viewer.render();
              }
```

Comment: Are you calling `camera.lookAt()` anywhere else? Or changing `camera.rotation` anywhere in your code?

Comment: I also tried , this code but rotates.  viewer.camera.position.set(X, Y, Z);
                   viewer.camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(X, Y, Z);
                  viewer.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(X, Y, Z));

Answer (score 0):

To move the camera in a linear fashion, you should just change its `.position` attribute. Something like:

`camera.position.x += 0.1;`

should do the trick. As long as you're not touching its `.rotation, .up` or other attribute, it should move in the axis you declare without rotating.

[See it in action in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/xozbLqrt/9/). All I'm doing is changing `.position.x += 1;` in line 40.

Comment: No , it still rotates. I do not see .rotation, .up

Comment: What do you mean it still rotates? The camera in the JSFiddle I posted is always facing forward, it never turns. I think you might be getting confused by the perspective of the camera: as it moves to the right, you can see the side faces of things, but that's the way perspective works. If you don't want any perspective distortions, you could use an orthographic camera.